# Can I populate a listview from getView of a custom adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview that contains items that have listviews. I am trying to populate item's listviews from inside the getView of the custom adapter that populates the "parent" listview:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    System.out.println("session adapter: here1");
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_session, null);


    }

    SessionObject i = sessions.get(position);

     if (i != null) {
         tvTrackName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewTrackName);
         tvTrackName.setText(i.trackName);
         tvSessionName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewSessionName);
         tvSessionName.setText(i.sessionName);

         tvSessionModerator = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewModeratorName);
         tvSessionModerator.setText("Moderator: "+i.sessionModerator);

         listAbstracts = i.abstractList;

         lvAbstracts = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewAbstracts);

         AbstractObjectAdapter adapter = new AbstractObjectAdapter(act, R.id.listViewAbstracts, listAbstracts);
         lvAbstracts.setAdapter(adapter);  
      }
     return v;  

}
```

The "interior" adapter seems to only be calling its getView function once, regardless of the number of items in its list. If there are 2 items, only the first gets put into the listview. Is this the wrong way to do this? Am I missing something?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: listview.setAdapter(yourcustomadapter);.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your item view dynamically, adding textviews to a linearlayout. You'll just have to be careful about handling the convertView, initially it will be easiest to always ingore it but you'll take a bit of a performance hit.

Optimise later.

Comment: Not really. I have a parent listview that should be scrollable, and it contains items that may have 1 or more child-items. Can text views be dynamically added?

Comment: Sure you can add textviews dynamically to a linearlayout. Just make sure you handle the convertview properly, the easiest thing to do would be to just ignore the convert view and create the view from new each time. You'll be taking a scrolling performance hit but try that first and then attempt to salvage the converview in a later iteration.

Comment: That makes more sense that what I am trying. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I've adjusted my answer to reflect the solution, I'd appreciate if you could accept the answer.

Comment: If you found this answer useful to you could you please accept?